# Javascript get single word before a specific string

Tags: javascript

I have two strings like below.

(1-50 of 128 search records)
(128 search records in total)

I need to extract only the word 128 which is just a previous word of "search". Can anyone guide me how to extract it in javascript?

Answer (score 4):

You can use lookahead (?="the text after here") to get the number which before a white space and `"search"` word

```js
const getResultNumber = (str) => {
  return str.match(/\d+(?=\ssearch)/)[0]
}

console.log(getResultNumber("1-50 of 128 search records"))
console.log(getResultNumber("150 search records in total"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the classic `indexOf()` variant with `slice()`.

```js
const str = "(1-50 of 128 search records)";

const inBetween = ["of", "search"];
const result = +str
  .slice(
    str.indexOf(inBetween[0]) + inBetween[0].length,
    str.indexOf(inBetween[1])
  )
  .trim();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this.

```js
let string = '(1-50 of 128 search records)';
let arr = string.match(/\w+/g); // ["1", "50", "of", "128", "search", "records"]
console.log(arr[3]);
```